# Deadlock when delete using OR operator

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, delete

I got a deadlock when having more than one sessions doing the following:

1. start transaction
2. insert data to table A
3. delete data from table A
4. commit

at the same time

They may delete the same records or different

I could replicate it with a simplified code like below, the table is empty at the start

Session 1:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @component_id  numeric = 1
DECLARE @relative_component_id  numeric = 0

INSERT INTO component_lock(area_id, component_id, generic_id, operator_id, session_id, lock_date, lock_type) 
VALUES(1, @component_id, 1, 1, 1, '1/1/2018', 1)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

DELETE FROM component_lock
WHERE area_id = 1
AND (component_id = @component_id OR component_id = @relative_component_id)
AND operator_id = 1 
AND generic_id = 1
AND session_id = 1

COMMIT
```

Session 2

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @component_id  numeric = 2
DECLARE @relative_component_id  numeric = 0

INSERT INTO component_lock(area_id, component_id, generic_id, operator_id, session_id, lock_date, lock_type) 
VALUES(1, @component_id, 1, 1, 1, '1/1/2018', 1)

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

DELETE FROM component_lock
WHERE area_id = 1
AND (component_id = @component_id OR component_id = @relative_component_id)
AND operator_id = 1 
AND generic_id = 1
AND session_id = 1

COMMIT
```

The primary key is (area_id, component_id, generic_id)

The foreign key is (operator_id)

There are 2 indexes on component_id and operator_id (nonclustered)

Deadlock graph
[image]

Actual execution plan of the delete query from session that was not chosen as the deadlock victim
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryyPArbi7

The deadlock does not happen if I remove the OR operator and change it to 2 delete queries

```
DELETE FROM component_lock
WHERE area_id = 1
AND (component_id = @component_id)
AND operator_id = 1 
AND generic_id = 1
AND session_id = 1

DELETE FROM component_lock
WHERE area_id = 1
AND (component_id = @relative_component_id)
AND operator_id = 1 
AND generic_id = 1
AND session_id = 1
```

Actual execution plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy9ACrbsm

Can anyone please explain to me why the difference?

Comment: Indexes? Plans?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have added more details

Comment: @MikeMinhLe, it's better to [upload actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) XML and add the link to your question rather than post images. For the deadlock, add the deadlock XML graph to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not about how many delete operations there are, it’s about how it finds the rows that are to be deleted.

If you look at the query plans you’ll almost certainly let see that your delete with OR is scanning the whole table. This will take out locks to make sure the rows don’t move around while it’s looking for ones to delete. Meanwhile, your inserts will take out locks, as the table and other indexes are maintained. Without the OR, you’re getting Seek operations, and only small parts of the table are locked.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's what I thought at first, however checking the actual execution plan, it shows that Clustered Index Seek is used for both cases (with OR or without)

Comment: @MikeMinhLe if there's only two rows, they'll both be on the same page. In this instance the whole table is equal to that one page (minus the metadata)

Comment: If you look at the “Actual Number of Rows Read”, is there a discrepancy between the two types of plans?

Comment: HI Rob, I checked the actual rows using Plan Explorer and they are the same (=1) for both plans. In my test, @relative_component_id is 0, so it does not match any row in the table

Comment: No, I mean the Actual Number of Rows Read, not the Actual Number of Rows.

Comment: Compare the Seek Predicate to the Predicate. In the one with the OR the Predicate is doing all the work. This means the seek portion of the operation is looking through a large number of rows, and the Predicate is filtering. It’s scanning through all the rows that are Area1.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the info. I couldn't see the "Actual Number of Rows Read", but the Seek Predicate is Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [R9Dev].[dbo].[component_lock].area_id = Scalar Operator((1.)), so like you said, it seems to scan all rows with area 1. Could you please explain why it scan all rows like that with OR, instead of just filtering the rows that match? Is there anyway to avoid that beside using 2 queries?

Comment: It does filter - it just does it through the predicate rather than the seek. The existence of an index on Area_ID means that it sees an opportunity to use a single index rather than two. Without that index it would have probably done it with two separate Seek operators.

Comment: Thanks Rob, why would it uses area_id index instead of the primary one (area_id, component_id, generic_id) when OR is being used?

Comment: There are a lot or factors involved, but it might think it’s less effort to scan the whole area_id rather than doing two seeks.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your delete query with a select to select all primary key columns and then delete the rows using only primary key columns

```
SELECT component_id, generic_id, area_id 
INTO #temp
FROM component_lock
WHERE area_id = 1
AND (component_id = @component_id OR component_id = @relative_component_id)
AND operator_id = 1 
AND generic_id = 1
AND session_id = 1

DELETE FROM component_lock cl
JOIN #temp t ON t.area_id = cl.area_id and t.generic_id = cl.generic_id and t.component_id = cl.component_id
```

This will change the locking pattern and hopefully will resolve the deadlocks.